# How to order by count desc in each group in a hive?

Tags: group-by, hql, hive

Here's the HQL:

```
select A, B, count(*) as cnt from test_table group by A, B order by cnt desc;
```

The sample output is as follows:

```
a1 | b1 | 5
a2 | b1 | 3
a1 | b2 | 2
a2 | b2 | 1
```

But what I want is to do the `order by` in each group of A, and the intended output is like:

```
a1 | b1 | 5
a1 | b2 | 2
a2 | b1 | 3
a2 | b2 | 1
```

Could anyone can give me some idea how to resolve this problem in just **one** HQL? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 26):

```
select A, B, count(*) as cnt 
from test_table 
group by A, B 
order by A, cnt desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

If you want only order of A then:

```
select A, B, count(*) as cnt from test_table group by A, B order by A asc;
```

If you want order of A and B then:

```
select A, B, count(*) as cnt from test_table group by A, B order by A asc,B asc;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want. I intend to do the order by count in every sub group of the result. As you can see in my post. Thx anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

```
select A, B, count(*) as cnt from test_table group by A, B order by A asc, B asc, cnt desc;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16838656)

Comment: I thought his question is to do an order by count with highest on top in every sub group of the result and rest other two columns in order. Can I ask why this does not provide an answer?

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).